# SQL query to make all data in a column UPPER CASE?

Tags: sql, uppercase

I need a SQL query to make all data in a column UPPER CASE?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Permanent:

```
UPDATE
  MyTable
SET
  MyColumn = UPPER(MyColumn)
```

Temporary:

```
SELECT
  UPPER(MyColumn) AS MyColumn
FROM
  MyTable
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to *only update on rows that are not currently uppercase* (instead of all rows), you'd need to identify the difference using [`COLLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET    MyColumn = UPPER(MyColumn)
WHERE  MyColumn != UPPER(MyColumn) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

---

#### A Bit About Collation

Cases sensitivity is based on your collation settings, and is typically case insensitive by default.

Collation can be set at the [Server, Database, Column, or Query](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-case-sensitivity-sql-server.cfm) Level:

```
-- Server
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
-- Database
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases
-- Column 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

[Collation Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/sql-server-collation-name-transact-sql) specify how a string should be encoded and read, for example:

- `Latin1_General_CI_AS` → Case Insensitive
- `Latin1_General_CS_AS` → Case Sensitive