# The most efficient way to UPPER CASE two columns in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I simply want to know if its possible to update and set two columns simultaneously to upper case in a single UPDATE statement with reference to oracle sql.

Comment: Given your question: yes, it is possible.

Comment: If you tried it you would find out. This is so basic a question it's hard to believe that knowing the answer would help you.

Comment: its late at office . so i apologize for asking such thing. Actually i did tried with a comma seperated.It din't worked at that time but the problem was something else which i figured out after reading your nice comments. Thanks for commenting and voting down . This only got me thinking again .

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to make all data in a column UPPER CASE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858528/sql-query-to-make-all-data-in-a-column-upper-case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this some kind of trick question?

```
update yourtable set columna=upper(columna), columnb=upper(columnb)
```

Comment: You misspelled "silly".

Comment: That's the easiest chunk of rep you'll ever earn :)